# Can I bind a file via stream to a QSqlQuery?

Tags: sql, qt, stream

I thought something like the following might be possible:

```
QFile f("thumbnail.jpg");
f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream ds(&f);
query->bindValue(":data", ds, QSql::In | QSql::Binary);
```

However the database field ends up with a NULL in it. The only thing I can get working currently is this:

```
QByteArray ba = f.readAll();
query->bindValue(":data", ba, QSql::In | QSql::Binary);
```

Which I suppose is fine, but I'd prefer to either stream it or make the structure more memory reusable (ie. like a vector).

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, you need to open the file before you use in stream.

So try something like below.

```
QFile f("thumbnail.jpg");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); //OPEN THE FILE BEFORE ASSIGNING TO STREAM
QDataStream ds(&f);
query->bindValue(":data", ds, QSql::In | QSql::Binary);
```

Comment: True, however that was a copy/paste oversight when I wrote the question. I will edit the question to fix.